# How do I set up an XUL document to be the front end of a application using Gecko?

Tags: c++, user-interface, xul, xpcom, gecko

How do I set up an XUL document to be the front end of a application using Gecko or XUL Runner?? Or is there no way to do it? Could someone provide an brief example if it is possible? Or link to a website?
From what I've read, it can't be a standalone application, and it involves using XPCOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Creating XPCOM Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_XPCOM_Components) from the Mozilla developers' network seems to be quite a good guide. It walks you through creating a XPCOM component with every step. That guide might be a bit hard to understand though, and [Creating a C++ XPCOM Component](http://www.iosart.com/firefox/xpcom/) from iosart.com might be easier

[Firefox addons developer guide / Using XPCOM—Implementing advanced processes](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Firefox_addons_developer_guide/Using_XPCOM%E2%80%94Implementing_advanced_processes) and [XUL Tutorial / XPCOM_Interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/XPCOM_Interfaces), also from the developers' network, explain how to use an XPCOM component inside XUL

You can then run the program by calling XULRunner on the XUL